# Android App crash when ask for permission

Tags: java, android, permissions

I need 2 permissions for my app= Location and Record Audio. I check, if it was granted, if no, I ask for permission. The code, where I ask for permisssion looks like this=

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // ask for permission
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1);
    } else {
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 2000, 0, locationListener);
    }

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // ask for permission
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO}, 2);
    }
}
```

My onRequestPermissionsResult method looks like this=

```
@Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        switch(requestCode) {
            case 1:
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 2000, 0, locationListener);

                }
            }

            case 2:
                permissionToRecordAccepted  = grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
                break;

        }
    }
```

When i install the apk on my phone and change to that activity, where I need this 2 permissions, the app crashes in the background, but the permission windows for location is still open,when I grant it and reopen the app, change to that activity, I just have to give Location permission and everything works fine. Why does my app crash? When I only had location permission, it worked fine, after inserting audio record permission, it closes. When I run this on my emulator, it doesnt crash.

Comment: show your exception stacktrace

Answer (score 2):

you should `requestPermissions` once with array of all needed permissions and you have two separated calls - second one will be called, when your app is already in background (because dialog with location permission appeared)

easiest fix would be adding `return` in proper place for checking is this the case (without stacktrace of exception its hard to guess)

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // ask for permission
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1);
        return; // return in here
    } else {
    ///... rest of code
```

better approach would be summing up all needed permissions and calling `requestPErmissions` once

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
    boolean needLocPerm = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
    boolean needAudioPerm = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;

    String[] permsArray = null;
    if(needAudioPerm && needLocPerm ){
        permsArray = new String[]{Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO,
                                 Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION};
    }
    else if(needAudioPerm){
        permsArray = new String[]{Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO};
    }
    else if(needLocPerm ){
        permsArray = new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION};
    }
    if(permsArray!=null && permsArray.length>0)
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, permsArray, 123);
    else locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 2000, 0, locationListener);
}
```

after this code improvement you should refactor your `onRequestPermissionsResult` method and check which permissions were granted (inspect `String[] permissions`  and `int[] grantResults` arrays)

without a stacktrace of exception this is only guess, besides above problem everything looks fine, but there is a chance your exception is fired by some call made in another method, e.g. `onPause`